# How to implement a better sliding window algorithm?

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, sliding-window

So I have been writing my own codes for HoG and its variant to work with depth images. However, I am stuck with testing my trained SVM in the detection window part.

All that I've done right now is to first create image pyramids out of the original image, and run a sliding window of 64x128 size from top left corner to bottom right.

Here's a video capture of it: http://youtu.be/3cNFOd7Aigc

Now the issue is that I'm getting more false positives than I expected.

Is there a way that I can remove all these false positives (besides training with more images) ? So far I can get the 'score' from SVM, which is the distance to the margin itself. How can I use that to leverage my results ?

Does anyone have any insight in implementing a good sliding window algorithm ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you could do is add a processing step to find the locally strongest response from SVM. Let me explain.

What you appear to be doing right now:

> for each sliding window `W`, record `category[W] = SVM.hardDecision(W)`

Hard decision means it return a boolean or integer, and for 2-category classification could be written like this:

```
hardDecision(W) = bool( softDecision(W) > 0 )
```

Since you mentioned OpenCV, in `CvSVM::predict` you should set `returnDFVal` to true :

> returnDFVal – Specifies a type of the return value. If true and the problem is 2-class classification then the method returns the decision function value that is signed distance to the margin, else the function returns a class label (classification) or estimated function value (regression).

from [the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html#cvsvm-predict).

What you could do is:

> 1. for each sliding window `W`, record `score[W] = SVM.softDecision(W)`
> 2. for each W, compute and record:
>
>    - `neighbors = max(score[W_left], score[W_right], score[W_up], score[W_bottom])`
>    - `local[W] = score[W] > neighbors`
>    - `powerful[W] = score[W] > threshold`.
> 3. for each `W`, you have a positive if `local[W] && powerful[W]`

Since your classifier will have a positive response for windows cloth (in space and/or appearance) to your true positive, the idea is to record the scores for each window, and then only keep positives which

- are a locally maximum score (greater that its neighbors) --> `local`
- are strong enough --> `powerful`

You could set threshold to 0 and adjust it until you get satisfying results. Or you could calibrate it automatically using your training set.

Comment: Great answer, but I have few more questions if you or anyone else don't mind. How do I use it together with scale space ? Do I treat detected window in another scale as just another neighbour ? And how does Non Maximal Suppression comes into play ? Anyway, still, thanks alot for your clear answer.

Comment: Good question about scales! You could indeed include scale in the neighborhood (left/right/up/down/smaller/larger), but it depends a lot on your data and end-goal - do you get a lot of multi-scale false positives? Unfortunately trial-and-error is the best practical methodology in computer vision. About non-maximal suppression, well what I described is a form of non-maximal suppression (you only keep local maximums).